# Clang unable to find GLEW framework

Tags: c++, macos, clang, linker-errors, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to build a project using GLEW (via point cloud library) on OS X 10.10 using clang++, and when I go to compile I get the error

```
ld: framework not found glew
```

In fact, even running `clang++ -framework glew` results in the same error.

The GLEW framework is present in `/System/Library/Frameworks/GLEW.framework`, and running clang with any other framework in that directory, like `clang++ -framework Cocoa`, results in what you'd expect, e.g. no input file rather than framework not found.

I'm still new to programming on OS X so I'm not sure how the whole framework structure works. Just to be sure I'm doing everything right, I tested it also with a simple hello world `test.cpp` file and a CMakeLists.txt file as follows which should certainly work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(glew_test)

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLEW_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(testg test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testg ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

GLEW is found by find_package, but I STILL get

```
ld: framework not found glew
```

I've also reinstalled GLEW several times (using homebrew) both from a binary package and from source, reinstalled PCL, and restarted my computer.

Comment: I have the same problem and [this github issue seems related](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/492), as [does this](https://github.com/fran6co/homebrew-cv/issues/13). Did you solve it?

Comment: Thanks; I did solve it, but not in any clever way. I don't remember exactly what I did but basically I took the reinstalling a little bit farther; I uninstalled and reinstalled anything that could be possibly related (xcode, all of homebrew, PCL) which fixed things.

Comment: @AndrewHundt It works by using `-lGLEW` in the linker options.

Comment: @sudoankit `-lGLEW` makes several assumptions one should not make, it will break if glew isn't on your path and [-l is a CMake antipattern](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/). Also I think someone submitted a github pull request to PCL and it has been fixed for quite a while, but thanks! :-)